# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\BlockChain\IPFS\node_modules\ipfs-http-client\package.json

Tags: node.js, ipfs

I am working on a project where I just want to save some data in the IPFS. I am using node.js and Infura to do this. But while running the code I get

```
D:\BlockChain\IPFS>node app.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:585
      throw e;
      ^
"Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\BlockChain\IPFS\node_modules\ipfs-http-client\package.json"
```

My code :

```
const { create } = require("ipfs-http-client");
const fs = require("fs");
// Login to infura.io and go to IPFS to create a project, after creating the project you will get the INFURA_SECRET_KEY and INFURA_ID set them here.
const INFURA_ID = "";// made empty for security purpose
const INFURA_SECRET_KEY = "";// made empty for security purpose
const auth =
  "Basic " +
  Buffer.from(INFURA_ID + ":" + INFURA_SECRET_KEY).toString("base64");
async function ipfsClient() {
  const ipfs = await create({
    host: "ipfs.infura.io",
    port: 5001,
    protocol: "https",
    headers: {
      authorization: auth, // infura auth credentails
    },
  });
  return ipfs;
}

async function saveText() {
  let ipfs = await ipfsClient();

  let result = await ipfs.add(`welcome ${new Date()}`);
  console.log(result);
}
saveText();
```

I've tried updating my node version , using `npm update` ,`npm audit fix --force`,deleting the `package-lock.json` and every possible solution. But in vain. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

At last solved the problem by degrading the **ipfs-http-client** version to **53.0.1**
code :

```
npm install ipfs-http-client@53.0.1
```

more details: [github issues](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/4256)